# how to write sql query from one page to another

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, web-applications

I am currently working on my first website. The problem I have encountered is the following: I have created a paged titled "CustomerList" that obviously list customers from an sql server DB. I have made the records clickable without using the select button that is included in the GridView. When I click a record, it takes me to my desired page. However, I can't seem to find a way to write an sql query from that click event to my desired page. The following is my code for the click event:

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;

    if (row.RowIndex == 0)
    {
        Response.Redirect("UsageHistoryPage.aspx? EntityID=" 
            + row.Cells[0].Text);
    }            
}
```

As you can see, when I click an index, I go to the "UsageHistoryPage". I've also added row.cells.[0] to take that data and write it to the UsageHistoryPage, which in my case, would be the customers name at the top of the page. Can someone please help me with this? Does anyone have a good tutorial link? thanks.

Comment: where does SQL feature? it isn't obvious from the question. Also; you should probably remove the extra space here: `.aspx? EntityID=`

Comment: You may also want to look at Tutorials on how to do use Request.QueryString(EntityId) in your example

Comment: @DJKRAZE its request.querystring

Comment: here is a site you can look at MSDN for reference 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: @MarcGravell, I understand the DB code required, I just can't figure out how to write the result in the page I am redirecting to.

Comment: @Rick so if the issue is unrelated to the redirect... why show us that? You should be able to get the query-string parameter from the request object, and then you're set, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this code - Add this code on your `UsageHistoryPage`

```
var input =  Response.QueryString["EntityId"];
var connectionString = "...";

var queryString = "SELECT Name FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN=@EntityId";
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
               connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();    
    using(var command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection))
    {
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EntityId",input) 
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Response.Write(String.Format("For Rick Your Name is here{0}", reader[0]));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Aghilas, where are you showing the OP the usage of the Response.Redirect("UsageHistoryPage.aspx? EntityID=" + row.Cells[0].Text); he is getting his info from a DataGrid that he clicks on..

Comment: Yes you add this code in UsageHistoryPage, i'am sorry DJ KRAZE i come back two minutes

Comment: @AghilasYakoub, thanks for your input. However, I see this working for one click/customer. I want to avoid making a page per customer. Instead I would like to have the name of the customer I click on at the top of the usage page.

Comment: @Rick i'am happy to help you, i update my answer, i update my query in order to select Name

Comment: Rick you may need to update your question / issue that you are having ..otherwise you are going to get a lot of ambiguous responses

Comment: are you wanting the customer name to show up in the Page Title ..?

Comment: @DJ KRAZE , i don't speak very good english but OP is : " I can't seem to find a way to write an sql query from that click event to my desired page." so i think i completed your answer

Comment: After reading it again I think that your answer is on point My apology.. The OP has also stated something about wanting to show the Customer when the page launches that's why I provided my example however I believe that his correct answer is a mix of your answer and my response.. the OP needs to seriously clean up his answer

Comment: @DJKRAZE I am looking for a solution more like the one provided by Aguilas. I want the name of the customer I click on to appear at the top of the page but as a query result not as the actual title of the page as you suggested. The reason I want it to be a query result is because I would like to add more columns to this page eventually.

Comment: @AghilasYakoub thanks again for help. I tried your suggested method and it is close to what I want. I can see the name of the customer I clicked on but only that customer's name. My desired functionality is to click on any customer have that name appear on my redirected page. Is there any way where the "input" parameter could be more dynamic and depend on my click input?

Comment: @Rick i prefer your solution is more proper, because you can try with id of button, or send ClientId, but i prefer your solution with Cell.Text in parameter . i'am happy to help you,

Comment: @AghilasYakoub Do you mean to incorporate that into the method you suggested? or to take an approach such as the one DJ KRAZE suggested?

Comment: @Rick Exactly you can mix the two approach

Answer (score 1):

@Rick you may want to look at how to check if a row is selected for example you don't need the for loop but in my case example need to check if RowIndex is = 1 or > 0 not ==0

```
private void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in usersGrid.Rows)
    {
        if (this.usersGrid.SelectedRows.Count == 1)
        {
         // get information of 1st column from the row
         string selectedUser = this.usersGrid.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

What you need to do is something like this to make sure that a Row has been selected

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   DataGridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;

    if (this.row.SelectedRows.Count == 1)
    {
        Response.Redirect("UsageHistoryPage.aspx?EntityID=" + row.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].ToString());
    }
}
```

If you want to have the Customer's name show up, on the Page Load of the UsageHistorPage.aspx add this code

```
String strCustName = Request.QueryString["EntityID1"];
this.Page.Title = strCustName;
```

try something like that.. please let someone here know if any of the ideas are working for you.

Comment: thanks for your  input and yes I do want to see the selected customer's name on the top of the second page. I will try your suggested method to see how if it works.